# Cloudkit issue with private database and subscription?

Tags: ios, notifications, cloudkit

**Problem**

Bob's iPhone saves recordA in someZone in Bob's private database.

Bob's iPad receives subscription notification of changes and retreives recordA from someZone in user's private database.

Bob's iPod touch also receives subscription notification of changes and retrieves recordA from someZone in user's private database.

Bob's iPad deletes recordA in someZone in user's private database.

Bob's iPod touch and iPad (for some reason) receives a subscription notification of deletion. Bob's iPhone does not receive subscription notification.

**Expected Results**

Bob's iPad should not receive subscription notification of deletion. Only Bob's iPhone and iPod touch should receive subscription notfication.

This is stated in CKSubscription's documentation:

> When a record modification causes a subscription to fire, the server
>   sends push notifications to all devices with that subscription **except
>   for the one that made the original change to the record.**

The iPad made the deletion, therefore, the iPad should not be receiving the subscription notification.

**Actual Results**

The iPad receives the subscription notification of deletion, despite being the author of the original change to the record.

The iPhone does not receive the notification of deletion.

The iPod touch receives subscription notification of deletion.

**Additional Feedback**

It looks like the original author of the **record** (not the original author of the **change**) does not receive any notifications, no matter who deleted the record. This is inconsistent with the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known CloudKit bug. There is however a workaround for this. When you first touch the record by making a small change and then remove the record, then it works as described.

Comment: I think this is it: http://openradar.appspot.com/19226338 or this: http://openradar.appspot.com/18810914